# Extend SfRadioButton functionality in Xamarin.Forms using Syncfusion

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, radio-button, syncfusion

I have a Xamarin.Forms app targeted for Android and I am using SfRadioGroup and SfRadioButton from Syncfusion in order to present some options to the user. However, I want to provide more information about each specific choice that a user can make.

I think a good way to achieve that is by adding an information button next to each RadioButton that will open a popup with more info regarding that choice.

I have tried to include the RadioButton and the information button in a StackLayout or a Gird, but then the synchronization between the buttons will be lost. The RadioButtons need to be placed directly into the SFRadioButtonGroup, otherwise checking one of them will not uncheck the others. Using the FlowListView and a DataTemplate didn't work either.

The way I would do this in Wpf is by creating a new control that extends the RadioButton and for the control's view I would take the default Xaml and modify it in order to add an information button. However, I could not find the source code for the Xaml of SfRadioButton and that makes extending the control very difficult.

Is there a way in which I could extend or customize the SfRadioButton? If not, what alternatives do I have in order to add more information next to a user's choice?

Below is a simple code sample to illustrate what I want to achieve (this does not work because the direct parent of the RadioButtons is not the RadioButtonGroup but the StackLayouts)

```
 <buttons:SfRadioGroup
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="radioGroup"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Margin="10,5,10,0">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <buttons:SfRadioButton
            TextColor="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}"
            IsChecked="{Binding Option1, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Text="Individual"
            VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="1,1,1,1" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=OpenPopupInfoOption1}"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <buttons:SfRadioButton
            TextColor="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}"
            IsChecked="{Binding Option2, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Text="Sum"
            VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="1,1,1,1" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=OpenPopupInfoOption2}"/>
    </buttons:SfRadioGroup>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML because without it we would just be throwing hypothesis!

Comment: @G.hakim I have added a Xaml sample to better explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: I don't think you can do that as `buttons:SfRadioGroup` needs to have `buttons:SfRadioButton` as a direct child for this to work!!

Comment: @G.hakim Yes, I also wrote that in the initial question. That is why I was asking if there is another way to achieve my goal, maybe by extending the SfRadioGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the current behaviour of SfRadioGroup, list of RadioButtons will be considered as group only if RadioButton is added as a direct child in SfRadioGroup. In order to achieve your requirement, we can’t add SfRadioButton as direct child.

So, we can achieve your requirement by changing the state of other two SfRadioButton manually. Please refer the following code snippet.

Code Snippet:

```
private void GoogleChrome_StateChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons.StateChangedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            if(e.IsChecked.Value)  
            {  
                Instagram.IsChecked = false;  
                Skype.IsChecked = false;  
            }  
        }
```

**Sample**: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/226145/ze/RadioButtonSample1174471588

Also we have already added this feature request to our database.

We don’t have any immediate plans to implement this feature. At the planning stage for every release cycle, we review all open features. You can keep track of the feature from the feedback portal below.

https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/4463

**Note**: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Dhanasekar

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that in your way as you need to put the `buttons:SfRadioButton` under `buttons:SfRadioGroup` .

> what alternatives do I have in order to add more information next to a
>   user's choice?

I would give you a solution:

Put a `label` under each `SfRadioButton` and write the details in the label. Binding the label's IsVisible with `SfRadioButton`'s `ischecked`, so the label will show once the `SfRadioButton` `isChecked` otherwise the label is `invisible`.

If the information is very long, you can change the `label` to a `button` below the 
`SfRadioButton`. And click the button to pop up the information.

```
<buttons:SfRadioGroup
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="radioGroup"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Margin="10,5,10,0">


        <buttons:SfRadioButton
            x:Name="Sum"
            TextColor="Gray"
            IsChecked="{Binding Option2, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Text="Sum"
            VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="1,1,1,1" />

        <Label Text="detail Sum" BackgroundColor="Gray" BindingContext="{x:Reference Sum}" IsVisible="{Binding IsChecked}"/>


        <buttons:SfRadioButton
            x:Name="Individual"
        TextColor="Blue"
        IsChecked="{Binding Option1, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Text="Individual"
        VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="1,1,1,1" StateChanged="SfRadioButton_StateChanged"/>

        <Label Text="detail Individual" BackgroundColor="Gray" BindingContext="{x:Reference Individual}" IsVisible="{Binding IsChecked}"/>


    </buttons:SfRadioGroup>
```

Here is a gif you can review:

[image]

Reply me if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not exactly what I had in mind but still an acceptable way of solving the issue.